format a cell to display as 1000x bigger than actual value
I have a number of seconds in some cells.  However I would like the cell to display as milliseconds.  For instance, if the cell contains 0.1234567, I would like to display 123.4ms.  I have the same general question for microseconds, nanoseconds etc.
I know how to add the suffix (by adding "ms" to the Format Cell dialog's Category->Custom Type field), so I could just make a new row of cells that has the calculated value multiplied by 1000.  But while simple, it doesn't scale well.
I've seen advice to use a format of 0.### "ms" or #,### but these don't work. % seems to multiply by 100, but leaves a percent sign as a suffix even if I'm supplying my own suffix.
I'm currently using Home and Business 2019.

What exactly is the problem with creating a new row or column? You can fill all cells with the same formula.

Do you want to display variable units, depending on the scale of the value (i.e. "s", "ms", "µs", "ns" ?). If so, you will need to use conditional formats (based on range conditions), but also to adjust the number format before the actual unit between "quotation marks" in each format.

CTRL+1 will bring up the Format Cell dialog.
Custom (or User-defined in LibreOffice) setting allows to type in a format string, e.g.
0.##" ms" - but that does not transform the number in that cell, it just displays it as 0.12 ms - you have to have a formula multiplying it, i.e. by 1000 (i.e. 1E3) to get a true milliseconds value shown.
If you wish for an automated ms, µs, ns, ps and so on shown then you need a formula that uses the value after E in =TEXT(B1,"##0.0 E00") to help you dig out the prefix:
Note: this format string gives you an exponent divisible by three - as it explicitly says that there should be UP TO 3 (and at least 1) digit(s) before the decimal point.
i.e.
=MID("munp",-MID(TEXT(A1,"##0.0E0"),FIND("E",TEXT(A1,"##0.0E0"),1)+1,10)/3,1) & "s"
will display "ms" for millisecond values, "ns" for nano and "ps" for picoseconds.
Now, this handles m, n, p seconds only, you may easily extend it for lesser values.
BUT there is a problem with values larger than ms - feel free to try it out and find a solution.
There are multiple ways to do it.
EDIT: There OF COURSE has to be a micro prefix in the midst of it, u above for ease of entry. On many Linux:en CTRL+SHIFT+U 00b5 Enter will display as µ as you're done.
... AND @MGonnet, IFERROR() is a great contender here ;-)

The proposal presented by @Hannu is inspiring, but in my Excel, the scientific format with only E does not work, E must be followed by + or -. In addition, the list of prefixes lacks μ. Taking into account the whole, i.e. value and unit, my proposal would be as follows:
=LEFT(TEXT(A3,"??0,0E-0"), FIND("E",TEXT(A3,"??0,0E-0"))-1) & " " &
 IFERROR(MID("mµnp", -MID(TEXT(A3,"??0,0E-0"), 
 FIND("E",TEXT(A3,"??0,0E-0"))+1, 10)/3, 1), "") & "s"

In my case, the decimal separator is a comma, if someone uses a period, please change it in the format code.
To make the values in a formatted column nicely aligned, you need to use a monospaced font.


E alone for exponential format might be one difference between LibreOffice (which I use "at home") and Excel. You also have ?instead of # which I find surprising ;-p

In Excel, the ? in the format code displays a space if there is no digit to display. From Microsoft's documentation:
"Use a question mark (?) if you want to add spaces for non-significant zeros on either side of the decimal point so that the decimal points align when they are formatted with a fixed-width font, such as Courier New."

That is exactly what # is supposed to do, which might be inherited from old BASIC dialects and the "PRINT USING" statement there ;-)   [ Yes I am that old ]

In Excel, # displays a digit or nothing, ? displays a digit or a space. This matters in text columns.
